# How to generate an average time?

Tags: excel, google-docs

In Excel (actually Google Table, but it's very similar) I have a range (say `C8:C100`) display times in the format `HH:MM:SS` - for example `00:15:21` or `01:10:49`.

Is it possible to have one cell display the average time of the range `C8:C100`?

I have tried `=AVERAGE(C8:C100)` but the output (`0,016527777777778`) is pretty useless.

Comment: Related and possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3467608/139010

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt Ball's comment, I got it now.

`=AVERAGE(C8:C100)` was a decent result, I just had do adjust the output format. Thank you for linking me the related question.